# How to make IBM Watson Assistant welcome node starts the conversation with Node.js or Python?

Tags: python, node.js, ibm-cloud, watson-conversation

I try the conversation on the IBM cloud and every things works fine starting with the welcome node where I have set many context variables there, Now I want to use a back-end language like python or Node.js to try that so, But I only can send the request and get the response but can't make the welcome node starts the conversation like happens on the cloud, Is there a solution for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the welcome node to be triggered, send an empty string and empty context to the dialog.

Comment: Great! I also tried sending the request without `input` parameter and it worked too.